# Undo the CLEAN command on the portable hdd : DISKPART

Tags: external-hard-drive, diskpart

When using DISKPART I accidentally used the CLEAN command on my portable WD 500gb HDD. Now it is not showing as a drive in my computer, though shows as unallocated space in Disk Management.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) might be able to fix that.

1. Download System Rescue CD (live cd) and burn it to a disk or just download testdisk
2. run testdisk
3. choose to create a log file
4. choose the disk that you ran clean on
5. choose intel
6. choose analyze
7. choose quick search
8. confirm to preceed
9. testdisk should find the deleted partition
10. confirm to save the partition table.
11. check for files.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a little understanding on these, can you please specify some steps..

Comment: This assumes they need to recover data, not just get the drive back up.  For recovery, Testdisk rocks. But beware that if your drive was pretty full then it may take days to recover all the data on it.  It is also likely to be in a random order, not in the nice, neat folders you may have had.

Comment: YESS!! It is back :)

Comment: Excellent, it is always nice when we can so easily undo. LOL

Comment: This is true. Back up your data.

Comment: Thanks @DaveYork so much, your tip saved my data and my life :D

Comment: @DaveYork on my laptop internal hard disk, I ran clean command on disk 1 i.e. My entire data is gone, there is lots of code, pictures of my life, I do not have any backup. Now I do not have Windows installation on my laptop,.please tell me how can I recover all data, I can not loose  data.

Comment: I did exactly this but it didn't detect my lost partition on the drive any idea what would have gone wrong?  I am pretty sure I didn't write anything on the drive. :(

Comment: how exactly did you lose the partition?

Comment: You saved my life sir :) I got all my files back in the fastest way

Answer (score 2):

If there's data on the disk that needs to be recovered, don't do this!

You'll need to recreate a partition and format it. Diskpart is capable of doing both:

- `select disk 1` or whatever number refers to your hard drive, use `list disk` to find out.
- `create partition primary` will create one large partition. Use `help create partition primary` for more options.
- `select partition 1`
- `format quick` to create the file system. Once again, check `help format` for more options.

Comment: Hey you said format? I have datas in the portable!!